# How to write a pattern that excludes a string from the filename in a vim autocmd

Tags: vim, autocmd

I'd like to define different mappings for files which have the same suffix.

E.g. define a general mapping for all ruby files and a different mapping only for rspec files:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *_spec.rb map <Leader>t :w!<cr>:!rspec %<cr>
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.rb map <Leader>t :w!<cr>:!rspec %:r_spec.rb<cr>
```

The above solution does not work on my machine, because the second `au` "overwrites" the first one.

Is it possible to write this kind of `au`?

**Update**: just placing the most specific (spec) one below the generic one (rb) works if I have only one buffer opened. As soon as I open a spec file, the *.rb mapping is lost for the regular ruby files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reversing the `autocommands` and adding `<buffer>` should get you the desired behavior in this case, i.e.:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.rb      map <buffer> ,t action2
au BufNewFile,BufRead *_spec.rb map <buffer> ,t action1
```

This ordering will achieve the proper per-filename mappings.

But you should note that when opening `*_spec.rb` files, **both** `map` commands will run: `action1` **and** `action2`. This can be un-desireable for certain commands.

Also, if you've set `<Leader>` to comma: <kbd>,</kbd>, then your mappings should look like this:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.rb      map <buffer> <Leader>t action2
au BufNewFile,BufRead *_spec.rb map <buffer> <Leader>t action1
```

Comment: First, thank you for the tip about the <Leader> key. Second, it works only if I have one buffer opened. If I have the spec file and the ruby file, each one in one buffer in a split window, for some reason the spec mapping is overriding the ruby mapping. Any suggestions?

Comment: It probably depends on what action1 and action2 are. Try using a "local" option. (e.g. `map <buffer> <Leader>t action2`). See `:help map-local`

Comment: I've updated the question using the real mappings I'm trying to define. They basically run the spec file if I have the spec or the subject open.

Comment: Try `map <buffer> <Leader>t etc.`

Comment: No, they should not look like `<leader>t`  (and, by the way, there is `<localleader>` for filetype-specific things). Why obfuscate the reading? `<leader>` is used to add basic ability for customizing mappings in plugins (which itself is not enough), it is not for user’s own use: you get used to type `,t`, not `<leader>t`. More, I use `,` as leader for my own mappings, but never set `mapleader` to it in order to prevent plugins from spoiling them.

Answer (score 0):

Do the more specific one last. In other words, reverse the order of those two commands.

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.rb map <buffer> ,t action2
au BufNewFile,BufRead *_spec.rb map <buffer> ,t action1
```

One command is still overriding the other, but this way it achieves the effect you want. Note that you might want to use a more specific map like `nmap`, or better yet `nnoremap`, so that you don't run into issues with this map in other modes.

Comment: be sure to add the <buffer> to the `map` commands in your solution.